# Error: [$compile:tplrt] Template for directive 'header' must have exactly one root element

Tags: angularjs

I want to implement **angular header and footer directives** for layout(index.html) page.

getting **Error: [$compile:tplrt] Template for directive 'header' must have exactly one root element.**

This is **index.html** (requirejs included)

```
<div>   
   <div header ></div>
    <div>main content here{{1+2}} </div>
    <div footer></div>
</div>
```

**header.html**:

```
<!--- angular header-->
<div>
    some stuff
</div>
<div>
    some other stuff
</div>
<!--- angular header-->
```

**header.js** (directive)

```
angular.module('header', [])
.directive('header', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A', //This menas that it will be used as an attribute and NOT as an element. I don't like creating custom HTML elements
        replace: true,
        //scope: {user: '='}, // This is one of the cool things :). Will be explained in post.
        templateUrl: base_url+"angular/js/directives/admin/header.html",
         controller: ['$scope', '$filter', function ($scope, $filter) { 
            // Your behaviour goes here :) 
        }] 
    }
});
```

*When I comment to templateUrl, Error get removed.*

**app.js**

```
var base_url="http://localhost/angular_layout/";
define(['angularAMD','header', 'ngRoute', ], function (angularAMD) {
var app = angular.module('angularapp', ['header','ngRoute' ]);  
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
/* *************** routes *************** */
............
```

**main.js**

```
//var base_url="http://localhost/ums/angular/js";
require.config({ 
baseUrl: "http://localhost/angular_layout/angular/js",
    paths: {
        'header': 'directives/admin/header',
        'footer': 'directives/admin/footer',
        'angular': 'lib/angular.min',
        'ngRoute': 'lib/angular-route.min',
        ..........
```

**Note:** *there is no problem if not the concept of this header and footer directives.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when your header.html does not have a root element. Change your header.html code to this:

```
<div>
    <!--- angular header-->
    <div>
        some stuff
    </div>
    <div>
        some other stuff
    </div>
    <!--- angular header-->
</div>
```

Comment: 1 q.: can I write script src tags in header or footer (or both) ?

Comment: That's another question. Post that one and we can answer it separately.

Comment: Yes. I got it. Thanks for the answer! 

Accepted.